# Install R packages using Dockerfile

Tags: r, docker, package, dockerfile

I am trying to install R packages using Dockerfile.

I installed the image [Rocker/Rstudio](https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/rstudio).

The content of the Dockerfile is:

```
# Base image https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/rstudio
FROM rocker/rstudio:latest

## Create directories
RUN mkdir -p /rstudio
RUN mkdir -p /rscripts


##Install R packages
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('rvest', 'jsonlite', 'data.table' ,'stringr'), repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org')"
```

I then build my image doing: `docker build -t my_r_image .`
The image builds but the packages are not installed as I get this warning:

> Installing packages into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’ (as ‘lib’ is
>   unspecified) Warning: unable to access index for repository
>   http://cran.us.r-project.org/src/contrib:   cannot open URL
>   'http://cran.us.r-project.org/src/contrib/PACKAGES'

I tried by replacing `http://cran.us.r-project.org` by `= 'http://cran.rstudio.com/')"` but I get a similar error saying that it is unable to access index for repository.

Anyone has an idea of what I am doing wrong?

edit1: See below output I get when I do:

```
.libPaths()
    [1] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" "/usr/local/lib/R/library"     

install.packages(c('rvest', 'jsonlite', 'data.table' ,'stringr'), repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org')
        Warning in install.packages :
          unable to access index for repository https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2019-10-15/src/contrib:
          cannot open URL 'https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2019-10-15/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
        Installing packages into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
        (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
        Warning in install.packages :
          unable to access index for repository http://cran.us.r-project.org/src/contrib:
          cannot open URL 'http://cran.us.r-project.org/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
        Warning in install.packages :
          packages ‘rvest’, ‘jsonlite’, ‘data.table’, ‘stringr’ are not available (for R version 3.6.1)
```

Comment: When you go inside the container, and in to R, what is your `.libPaths()`? Are any of those setup on the directory? It might be worthwhile trying to debug inside a container without the line `RUN R -e "install.packages(c('rvest', 'jsonlite', 'data.table' ,'stringr'), repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org')"`, inside an R session.

Comment: Is there any networking restriction on the build host or on its processes? That kind of warning is common when networking glitches (temporary) or is restricted by policy.

Comment: @r2evans how could I check this? I selected the first EC2 instance available in AWS and then installed rocker/rstudio directly

Comment: @JonnyPhelps I edited my post with the command you suggested. I am not sure how could I know if those setup are on the directory?

Comment: Does anything trying to use the network (inside your build script) actually succeed? This looks a lot like the build container does not have internet access.

Comment: when I run `docker run hello-world` it runs successfully so I assume it is not a internet issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

strangely enough, with exactly the same Dockerfile, I had no problem installing the packages using the rocker/tidyverse repository instead of the rocker/rstudio. Anyone knows why is that?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, `FROM rocker/rstudio:latest`

For me, changing to an earlier version solved my issue and the libraries were able to install. In my case I used `FROM rocker/rstudio:4.0.1`